# nodemon stopping doesn't stop the process in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using nodemon in my nodejs app to auto restart when changes apply. But when I stop nodemon using 'Ctrl + C' in ubuntu environment, doesn't stop nodejs. I have to search the process that's running from the port and have to kill manually using kill -9 . How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

**Quick and dirty solution**

```
process.on('SIGTERM', stopHandler);
process.on('SIGINT', stopHandler);
process.on('SIGHUP', stopHandler);
function stopHandler() {
  console.log('Stopped forcefully');
  process.exit(0);
}
```

**Right solution**

Implementing `Graceful Shutdown` is a best practise. At this example, I should only stop the server. If the server will stop longer than 2s, then the process will terminate with exitcode `1`.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', stopHandler);
process.on('SIGINT', stopHandler);
process.on('SIGHUP', stopHandler);
async function stopHandler() {
  console.log('Stopping...');

  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(1);
    console.error('Stopped forcefully, not all connection was closed');
  }, 2000);

  try {
    await server.stop();
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error, 'Error during stop.');
    process.exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any shortcut key or something to do this? I mean pressing 'Ctrl + C' like?

Comment: CTRL+C will send signal SIGINT

Comment: The answer by [@galkin][1] is very good. The only problem for non-advanced users is that the terminal is hanged and won't respond until you kill the previous process and you may not want to kill them all, but only the one creating the conflict. For that do the following:

1.- find the process id by searching for the what process is listening for the port with: `netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':PORT'`

then `kill -9 ProcessID`
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850916/galkin